# QRegExp - How to get specific text between two HTML tags

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

I want to extract some text from the following HTML code in "**Qt/C++**" using `QRegExp`.

```
<TABLE border="0" width="99%">
  <COLGROUP><COL width="100"><COL>
  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EEEEFF"><B> MCT-to-KR</B>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EEEEFF"><FONT class="result">THIS IS THE TEXT WHICH I WANT TO FETCH</FONT>
  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#DDDDEE">Normalized
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#DDDDEE">[AL-LYA-A]
  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#CCCCDD">Web Unicode
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#CCCCDD">ANOTHER TEXT I MIGHT BE INTERESTED IN, BUT WOULD BE EASY TO GET IF THE FIRST IS DONE
</TABLE>
```

In **C#.Net** I could do it like this:

```
private Regex txtExtractor = new Regex(@"<FONT class=""result"">(.*?)</FONT>");
```

I tired it with `QRegExp` but didn't work, so how should I edit it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using QRegEx (Qt 4 and Qt 5)

```
QRegExp regex("<FONT class=\"result\">(.*)</FONT>");
regex.indexIn(html);
QString textYouWant = regex.cap(1);
```

### Using QRegularExpression (Qt 5)

```
QRegularExpression regex("<FONT class=\"result\">(.*)</FONT>");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(html);
QString textYouWant = match.captured(1);
```

I recommend using `QRegularExpression` if you're using Qt 5.  It's API is a bit nicer.